# Windows Azure: Slow connection to Azure VM and SQL database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have an Azure VM configured with IIS role and a web service application installed in it. This web service application makes a call to an Azure SQL Database.
When I first configured the servers, the connection was pretty good (1-2 seconds response time), in the past 2 days the connection to the server has been very slow (15-20 seconds response time when it doesn't timeout). Is there anything I should be aware of int he Azure servers to make the connection faster?